# ¿Cómo obtener el resultado de la consulta separado por comillas y coma en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola a todos tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SET @NotesByTherapy = (Select NotesIDs from MdNotesByTherapy Where TherapyCode = 'ADM')
```

esto me da como resultado:

```
433603037646,142
```

Quisiera que me lo devolviera de esta forma:

```
'433603037646','142'
```

O sea con las comillas, ¿alguien sabe cómo hacer esto en SQL?

La consulta anterior es una parte de una consulta más amplia aquí el ejemplo:

```
Select A.DefaultTherapyCode, A.CUSTOMFRAME,A.ENABLEEDIT,A.FREQUENCY,A.INCLUDESIGNATURE,A.ISATTACHMENT,A.ISBILLABLE,A.ISCUSTOM,
A.MAXLEN,A.MINLEN,A.NOTECODE,A.NOTESID,A.OVERRIDEATTENDANCE,A.PROVIDERID,A.STARTDAY,
A.STATUS,A.UNSCHEDULEDONLY,A.USECATEGORY,A.NOTESTEMPLATE,Coalesce( A.Description, B.Description ) as Description
from MdPrNotes A LEFT OUTER JOIN MDBIOPSYCHOSOCIALSETUPHDR B ON A.NoteCode = B.BioCODE
Where Status = 'A' AND ( ( UnscheduledOnly <> 'Y' ) OR ( UnscheduledOnly is null ) )  AND NotesID in (433603037646,142)
```

El error aquí está en lo último, que debe estar separado por coma y comillas
Cuando coloco las comillas de la forma que mostré anteriormente en la consulta amplia si devuelve perfecto los valores.

Comment: Hola JackNavaRow gracias por responder usando de esa forma me lo devuelve asi: '433603037646,142' deberia de salirme de esta forma '433603037646','142'

Comment: ese dato, sale de un solo registro o varios? porque por lo que decis abria que hacer todo ese trabajo manual.. y otra pregunta, esto es para solucionar un problema de que tipo? tal vez, lo que estas buscando no sea la solucion a lo que queres...

Comment: ¿qué tipo de dato es NotesIds?

Comment: el tipo de dato es text

Comment: gbianchi voy a editar la pregunta con mas detalles

Comment: Ah, ahora entiendo. Tienes una lista de ids separados por coma y lo que buscas es hacer un "split" de estos. La pregunta es ¿quieres cada id como una nueva columna o más bien como un conjunto de filas?

Comment: si exacto es una lista separado por comas, cada id como una nueva columna, la respuesta de Roger Torne funciono para mi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto, aunque simple te puede ayudar

```
SET @NotesByTherapy = (Select CONCAT('''', REPLACE(NotesIDs, ',', ''','''), '''') as NotesIDs from MdNotesByTherapy Where TherapyCode = 'ADM')
```

Reemplazamos la coma por comilla simple + coma + comilla simple y añadimos al inicio y final comillas simples.

Esto no sirve para campos del tipo `text`. En ese caso es necesario hacer un  `CAST` de la columna.

```
SET @NotesByTherapy = (Select CONCAT('''', REPLACE(CAST(NotesIDs as varchar(MAX)), ',', ''','''), '''') as NotesIDs 
from MdNotesByTherapy Where TherapyCode = 'ADM')
```

Comment: Al ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Comment: Si, es debido a que la columna es del tipo `text`. Es necesario hacer un cast. Corrijo la respuesta

Comment: exacto lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pides es un código que mal utilizado puede usarse como vulnerabilidad de inyección de SQL. Siempre es importante evitar la concatenación de valores en ejecuciones de código SQL.

La solución ideal sería no usar ninguna variable (y dar formato al código) así.

```
SELECT A.DefaultTherapyCode,
    A.CUSTOMFRAME,
    A.ENABLEEDIT,
    A.FREQUENCY,
    A.INCLUDESIGNATURE,
    A.ISATTACHMENT,
    A.ISBILLABLE,
    A.ISCUSTOM,
    A.MAXLEN,
    A.MINLEN,
    A.NOTECODE,
    A.NOTESID,
    A.OVERRIDEATTENDANCE,
    A.PROVIDERID,
    A.STARTDAY,
    A.STATUS,
    A.UNSCHEDULEDONLY,
    A.USECATEGORY,
    A.NOTESTEMPLATE,
    Coalesce(A.Description, B.Description) AS Description
FROM MdPrNotes A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MDBIOPSYCHOSOCIALSETUPHDR B ON A.NoteCode = B.BioCODE
WHERE STATUS = 'A'
    AND (
        (UnscheduledOnly <> 'Y')
        OR (UnscheduledOnly IS NULL)
        )
    AND NotesID IN (
        SELECT NotesIDs
        FROM MdNotesByTherapy
        WHERE TherapyCode = 'ADM'
        );
```

La otra opción es utilizar una función para separar los valores concatenados en valores atómicos. Esto se puede hacer en versiones recientes de SQL Server mediante la función STRING_SPLIT().

```
SELECT A.DefaultTherapyCode,
    A.CUSTOMFRAME,
    A.ENABLEEDIT,
    A.FREQUENCY,
    A.INCLUDESIGNATURE,
    A.ISATTACHMENT,
    A.ISBILLABLE,
    A.ISCUSTOM,
    A.MAXLEN,
    A.MINLEN,
    A.NOTECODE,
    A.NOTESID,
    A.OVERRIDEATTENDANCE,
    A.PROVIDERID,
    A.STARTDAY,
    A.STATUS,
    A.UNSCHEDULEDONLY,
    A.USECATEGORY,
    A.NOTESTEMPLATE,
    Coalesce(A.Description, B.Description) AS Description
FROM MdPrNotes A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MDBIOPSYCHOSOCIALSETUPHDR B ON A.NoteCode = B.BioCODE
WHERE STATUS = 'A'
    AND (
        (UnscheduledOnly <> 'Y')
        OR (UnscheduledOnly IS NULL)
        )
    AND NotesID IN (
        SELECT value  
        FROM STRING_SPLIT( @NotesByTherapy, ',')   
        );
```

En versiones anteriores, se puede usar la siguiente función creada por Jeff Moden y con mejoras de distintas personas incluyendo a Eirikur Eiriksson.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
 WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
GO
```